Export Android Google BOTH Contacts And Associated Assigned Groups to Excel
I have 4,000+ contacts. I need to export all Samsung Ultra Android contacts with their assigned group to Excel Whenever I have put in a contact, I assigned the contact to a group or different groups. For example, say it is John Doe and phone number. In case I would not recall John Doe, I assgne each contact to a group or set of groups, like California, Finance, Recruiter. That would be three groups that John Doe could be found. (Android Contacts app appears to be a Google app)
With 4,000+ contacts, I need to be able to segment. Therefore, I NEED BOTH THE CONTACTS AND THE ASSOCIATED GROUP/S that I assigned them to.
HELP, please!

If the contacts are synced with Google you can download all your (contact) data using Google Takeout.
